# C# List grouping and assigning a value

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of Orders. This list contains multiple orders for the same item, see the table below.

I then want to assign each item that is the same (i.e. ABC) the same block ID. So ABC would have a block ID of 1 & each GHJ would have a block ID of 2 etc. What is the best way of doing this?

Currently I order the list by Order ID and then have a for loop and check if the current Order ID is equal to the next Order ID if so assign the two the same block ID. Is there a better way of doing this using linq or any other approach?

```
Order ID             Block ID

ABC 
ABC
ABC
GHJ
GHJ
GHJ
MNO
MNO
```

Comment: Show us your code, please.

Comment: @okrumnow, not every question has to come with some arbitrary block of code. Adding code to this question would not improve it one bit. This is a perfectly clear and well formatted question, See [Should we be awarding A's for effort](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/should-stack-overflow-be-awarding-as-for-effort)

Comment: @Liam As the OP mentioned some code he had, showing that would have helped us how the data structures are defined and therefore we could have offered a tailored answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always depends of what *better* means for you in this context.

There are a bunch of possible solutions to this trivial problem.
On top of my head, I could think of:

```
var blockId = 1;
foreach(var grp in yourOrders.GroupBy(o => o.OrderId))
{
    foreach(var order in grp)
    {
        order.BlockId = blockId;
    }
    blockId++;
}
```

or (be *more "linqy"*):

```
foreach(var t in yourOrders.GroupBy(o => o.OrderId).Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, Int32.MaxValue), (grp, bid) => new {grp, bid}))
{
    foreach(var order in t.grp)
    {
        order.BlockId = t.bid;
    }
}
```

or (can you still follow the code?):

```
var orders = yourOrders.GroupBy(o => o.OrderId)
                       .Zip(Enumerable.Range(1, Int16.MaxValue), (grp, id) => new {orders = grp, id})
                       .SelectMany(grp => grp.orders, (grp, order) => new {order, grp.id});
foreach(var item in orders)
{
    item.order.BlockId = item.id;
}
```

or (probably the closest to a simple `for` loop):

```
Order prev = null;
blockId = 1;
foreach (var order in yourOrders.OrderBy(o => o.OrderId))
{
    order.BlockId = (prev == null || prev.OrderId == order.OrderId) ?
                    blockId :
                    ++blockId;
    prev = order;
}
```

Linq? Yes.
Better than a simple loop? Uhmmmm....

---

Using Linq will not magically make your code *better*. Surely, it can make it often more declarative/readable/faster (in terms of lazy evaluation), but sure enough you can make otherwise fine imperative loops *unreadable* if you try to force the use of Linq just because Linq.

---

As a side note:
if you want to have feedback on working code, you can ask at [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this that way, it will assign same blockid for same orderid

```
var ordered = listOrder.GroupBy(x => x.OrderId).ToList();
for (int i = 0; i < ordered.Count(); i++)
{
    ordered[i].ForEach(x=>x.BlockId=i+1);
}
```

it will group orders by orderid then assign each group next blockid. Note that it won't be done fully in linq, because linq is for **querying** not changing data.

Comment: Hi Wudzik, I tried your solution but couldn't quite get it to work. I had to change the for loop code to var grp = ordered[I].ToList(); grp.ForEach(ord => ord.BlockId =I; The foreach extension method would no appear otherwise